# Zip a folder and archive it using powershell

Tags: powershell

Im new to `powershell` and I would like to archive the folders using it

following are my folders in `C:\Bridge\Build\destination`

> Vista
>
> Tamil
>
> CSK

I want to archive these folders in `C:\Bridge\Build\Build_Achive\2020-05-15` with the file name  as `2020-05-1.zip`

The folder destination and file name will be generated based on current date and time stamp so I would like  to use the variable in destination and file name

I tried the following code its giving me error can anyone please help

```
$path = "C:\Bridge\Build\Build_Achive\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
    If(!(test-path $path))
        {
              New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\Bridge\Build\Build_Achive\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
              ECHO 'Created folder '  $path
        }
    ELSE 
        {
              Write-Host 'Folder ' ' - ' $((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))   ' - ' 'already exists'
        }
$FileLogdate = (Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss)



echo $path
echo $FileLogdate
$filename =$path\$FileLogdate
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Bridge\Build\destination -DestinationPath filename.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems in the last two lines:

1. Variable file name - you need to use quotes, as you are trying to create a string: `$filename ="$path\$FileLogdate`"
2. I believe you would like to compress the files not with name `filename.zip`, but with the content of the variable $filename: 
   `Compress-Archive -Path C:\TEMP\AdComputers_WindowsServer_2008.csv -DestinationPath $filename`